# C# and excel automation, how to use the CopyFromRecordset function

Tags: c#, .net, excel-automation

I am trying to populate an excel file with some data from a SQL server,

my code is as follows,

```
   public static void SQLToExcel(Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook, string SQL, string tFORMAT)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ANSICConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn;
        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();


        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn))
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();

                ((Range)xlWorkBook.Sheets["COVER"].Range("D6")).CopyFromRecordset(reader);


            }
            reader.Close();
        }


        conn.Close();


    }
```

I get the following error

{"No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))"}

do I need to convert the reader to an array?

Comment: Firstly, copyfromrecordset is no longer actively maintained so you might wand to look at OpenXML as an alternative.  Secondly, copyfromrecordset only works with an ADO connection.  So you need to add the ADODB library and use that to connect.  You will also find that there might be problems with GUIDs, etc. not working and other subtle changes to the way the SQL must be written.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa165427(v=office.10).aspx

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315974

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use `CopyFromRecordset` you need to replace `SqlDataReader` with `ADODB.Recordset`. Don't forget to add a reference to **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.x** library.